# Allow state-specific search in Careers

Tags: feature-request, jobs

It seems like there's no way to search for jobs **in specific state**, due to the fact that the geographic search imposes a mandatory minimum "10 mile distance" radius around your search area.

E.g., if you search for jobs in "NJ" (or any specific area in NJ that's within 10 miles of NYC), you get all the jobs in NY/NYC; which of course so completely drown out NJ jobs as to make the search useless.

I think the easiest solution UI-wise would be to allow "distance 0 miles" as an option; but I am not sure if it's feasible technologically. Or better yet, simply let the state name be a form option.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to limit your search to a specific state currently.  It's poorly done on the current UI but you actually are running a bounding box query at the state level and not a radius.  If you draw a rectangle around just about any state, you overlap other states and that is why you are getting non state results.

We've played around with limiting searches to a particular state, but then we decided *in most cases* it's kind of pointless to search a whole state.  Most people who are willing to move 400 miles across a state are really willing to relocate outside of their state as well.

I'd say this is still a query we'd like to support, but it's pretty low on the chart for now.

Comment: Can exclusion be implemented? E.g. "-NY"